# indexPath.row starts at 1 instead of 0 after reload

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I have 3 items in my db, I call tableView.reloadData() in viewDidLoad() the cells are retrieved from FireStore DB. But the db returns 3 items from the db even before print(indexPath.row) in cellForRowAt. I have a likes function and it breaks everytime I have more than 2 items and i suspect its because of this. Could a slow computer cause this problem?

print(indexPath.row) with 3 items in db returns:

0 1 2 1 2

with 2 items:

0 1 1

//cellForRowAt

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        
        let p = postList[indexPath.row]
        print("\(indexPath.row)")
//        print("\(p.postId)")
        cell.recipeName.text = p.recipeName
        profileDataManager.loadProfile(p.username){
            user in
            self.userList = user
            for i in self.userList{
                cell.userName.text = i.displayName
            }
        }
        cell.CLHLabel.text = "\(p.likes) likes, 10 comments, \(p.healthy) users find this healthy"
        cell.tagsLabel.text = "\(p.tagBudget), \(p.tagPrep), \(p.tagStyle)"
        cell.postID = p.postId
        cell.postItem = p
        cell.delegate = self
        
        let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: p.postImage)
        imageRef.getData(maxSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024) { [weak self] (data, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error downloading image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if let data = data {
                cell.postImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
        
        cell.loadCell()
        
        return cell
    }
```

//numberOfRowsInSection

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return postList.count
}
```

[how tableView looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVx9s.jpg)

Comment: I will be happy to provide any code

Comment: You should definitely provide any code in the question, and explain what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson okay i will add some of the relevant code

Comment: can you show numberOfSection and numberOfRowsInSection function

Comment: @aiwiguna Sorry for late reply, will add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue, my tableView had an auto-grow table function that looks something like this

```
class IntrinsicPostTableView: UITableView {

    override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }

}
```

this for some reason caused my indexPath.row to start at 1 instead of 0